# Validating a text field with int value

Tags: java, swing, integer, jtextfield

I'm using Netbeans IDE I want to validate a text field that use to type the discount percentage. so that I want to stop typing numbers more than 100 in keytyped event.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172267/how-to-restrict-the-jtextfield-to-a-x-number-of-characters and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield

Comment: private void tcs_discountKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
  
      String A = tcs_discount.getText();
   
try{  
int myint = Integer.ParseInt(A);  
   
if(!(myint >=0 && myint <= 100))  {
    
    
    evt.consume();
           
    
    
}

}


catch(Exception e)  
{  
  }  }

Comment: @HashainLakshan Don't, ever, use a `KeyListener` to try a filter a text component.  You have no guarantee in the order that the `KeyListeners` or called and the key stroke may already have been sent to the field before you.  They are also not called when the user pastes text into the field

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `KeyListener`s to try and filter text components.

Instead...

- Use a `DocumentFilter`.  This will allow you to filter the content of the field BEFORE it's applied to the document.  Check out [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [examples](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for more info
- Use a `JSpinner`. Check out [How to use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestSpinner02 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestSpinner02();
    }

    public TestSpinner02() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
                spinner.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 100, 1));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(spinner);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: can you give me a example from JSpinner

Comment: I did, follow the link [How to use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)