# How to limit JTextFiled to accept only numbers less then 10?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, restrictions

How to restrict a JTextFiled to accept only numbers less then 10, no words, no spaces or any other special characters?

Comment: For starters, better use a `JFormattedTextField` with a `NumberFormat`. I don't know off the top of the head how to limit the range though...

Comment: You can do this with a DocumentFilter.

Comment: well can't you check the length of the string that u received from the textfield and throw a warning of some sort?

Comment: oh dang..there is a pre defined method even for this !

Comment: Also check out my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172267/how-to-restrict-the-jtextfield-to-a-x-number-of-characters).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, `Then up-vote his answer because it is, as usual, clean, helpful and correct.`, normally I would agree, but as I have noted in the comments, that approach does not work for me. I did include my suggestion for a solution to this problem in the comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels have you heard of Swing JavaBuilders? I think it's a clean solution.

Comment: @Pureferret: no, I'm not familiar with this tool and will have to look into it. Do you have a link to its documentation?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest would be to use a component designed for this:

```
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
spinner.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(0, null, 10, 1));
```

Technically `JSpinner` is not derived from `JTextField`, it uses one internally for the editor part and thus looks like one (plus it has additional buttons to change the number with mouse clicks).

Answer (score 3):

Again, a DocumentFilter is one way to solve this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DocFilterExample extends JPanel{
   JTextField textfield = new JTextField(5);

   public DocFilterExample() {
      PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) textfield.getDocument();
      doc.setDocumentFilter(new MaxNumberDocFilter(10));

      add(textfield);
   }

   private class MaxNumberDocFilter extends DocumentFilter {
      private int maxNumber;

      public MaxNumberDocFilter(int maxnumber) {
         this.maxNumber = maxnumber;
      }

      private boolean verifyText(String text) {
         if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return true; // allow for a blank text field
         }
         int value = 0;
         try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(text);
            if (value >= 0 && value < maxNumber) {
               return true; // if it's a number in range, it passes
            }
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;  // if it's not a number, it fails.
         }
         return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
               AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String oldText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldText);
         sb.insert(offset, string);

         if (verifyText(sb.toString())) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
         }

      }

      @Override
      public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
               throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String oldText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldText);

         sb.replace(offset, offset + length, text);
         if (verifyText(sb.toString())) {
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String oldText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(oldText);

         sb.replace(offset, offset + length, "");

         if (verifyText(sb.toString())) {
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);            
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowUI() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Eg");
      frame.getContentPane().add(new DocFilterExample());
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

- Advantages:

  - no error messages are needed. Instead it simply prevents input of bad input.
  - It works for cut and paste just fine.
- Disadvantages:

  - no error messages are given, and so the user won't know why his text is not accepted.
  - it's a bit long and bulky.
  - it's not easy "chaining" -- using multiple filters at once, something Rob Camick has done some work on.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();

textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         //do stuff here when enter pressed
        String text = textField.getText();
        if(text!=null && !text.equals("")){
            char c = evt.getKeyChar();
            int val=Integer.parseInt(c);
            if(val>=48 && val<=57){
                if(Integer.parseInt(text)<=10){
                    //Its valid and allowed
                }else{
                    //Its invalid, show error message here
                }
            }else{
                //Show message only numbers are allowed
                return false;
            }           
        }

    }
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: An `ActrionListener` will only be fired when the enter key is pressed.  Either of the other answers provides a better solution here.

Answer (score -1):

Use Swing Javabuilders, where you can define your GUI in YML (below),  including Text Field validation.

You declare in your gui in a yaml file, here is an example for Person.java, called Person.Yaml:

```
JFrame(name=frame, title=frame.title, size=packed, defaultCloseOperation=exitOnClose):
        - JButton(name=save, text=button.save, onAction=[$validate,save,done])
        - JButton(name=cancel, text=button.cancel, onAction=[$confirm,cancel])
        - MigLayout: |
              [pref]              [grow,100]     [pref]             [grow,100]
              "label.firstName"   txtFirstName   "label.lastName"   txtLastName
              "label.email"       txtEmail+*
              >save+*=1,cancel=1
    bind:
        - txtFirstName.text: person.firstName
        - txtLastName.text: person.lastName
        - txtEmail.text: person.emailAddress
    validate:
        - txtFirstName.text: {mandatory: true, label: label.firstName}
        - txtLastName.text: {mandatory: true, label: label.lastName}
        - txtEmail.text: {mandatory: true, emailAddress: true, label: label.email}
```

The three blocks above are as follows:

The Swing Classes (JFrame, and JButton) as well as the Layout Manager, with *embedded* JLabels (`label.firstName` and `label.lastName`) which are recognised by the 'label' part of their declaration and the JTextFields (`txtLastName`,`txtFirstName` and `txtEmail` ) which are recognised by the txt part of their name.

The Data Binding: This binds `JTextArea.text` to `class.fieldName` so that when data is entered into the JTextField it is mapped to the fields.

Validation: Here is where the text is validated. Notice that the `JButton` with the name Save has in the `onAction` section has the entry `$validate` which runs the in-built validate method. This reads the kind of validation in from the validate block:

```
 txtFirstName.text: {mandatory: true, label: label.firstName}
```

Which declares the field *has to be filled in* (`mandatory: true`) and `txtEmail` must be filled with a valid email address (`emailAddress: true`). More validation is outlined below.

Once you've declared the GUI, you just run it like so, from within your java file.

```
    private BuildResult result;
    .....
    public methodName(){
        .....
    result = SwingJavaBuilder.build(this).setVisible(true);
    }
```

This method (`build(this)`) references a .yml file of the same name (so your gui is in person.yml and is paired with person.java).

There's more validation available in the documentation :

```
validate:
      - mandatory.text: {label: Mandatory Field, mandatory: true}
      - date.text: {label: Date Field, dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd"}
      - email.text: {label: E-Mail, email: true}
      - minmax.text: {label: Min/Max Length, minLength: 5, maxLength: 10}
      - regex.text: {label: Regex, regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9]+"}
      - regex2.text: {label: Regex, regex: "[a-zA-Z0-9]+", 
               regexMessage: "''{0}'' must be a number or letter"}
      - long.text: {label: Min/Max Long, minValue: 5, maxValue: 50, mandatory: true}
```

So you would want to use the last one `long.text` with this specification:

```
myValidNumberField{label: Number less than ten, maxValue: 10, mandatory: true}`
```

There's more information on the [github](https://github.com/jacek99/javabuilders) page, about setting your GUI up like this.

Comment: For those who can't wait,  here is an article that highlights the usage: http://java.dzone.com/articles/making-gui-builders-obsolete

Comment: did you drinking, please re_read your post here, description came from my mind

Comment: @mKorbel I'm not sure what you're saying, but I've added more to the answer.