# JTextField DocumentListener

Tags: java, jtextfield, jtextpane, documentlistener, documentfilter

Trying to get the value of a JTextField as it's being updated (chars inserted, chars removed, chars changed) and then setting it's value.

I've run into the "Attempt to mutate in notification" exception which lead me to:

*However, you should never modify the contents of a text component from within a document listener. If you do, the program will likely deadlock. Instead, you can use a formatted text field or provide a document filter.* from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

I'm using a document filter to limit the number of chars of the JTextField to 12 but I don't know how I can detect changes on the JTextField without using the document listener...which is the source of the exception

Any advice or SSCCE for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172267/how-to-restrict-the-jtextfield-to-a-x-number-of-characters?lq=1

Comment: @posdef As well as limiting the characters I want to fire an event on remove/add/change characters..

Comment: Use the second link. The `DocumentFilter` is the newer preferred approach.

Comment: `I want to fire an event on remove/add/change characters` - why? Do you mean "fire" or "listen" for an event? In any case the DocumentListener is invoked for additions and removals of text.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Wrap the logic of DocumentListener's events into SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to prevent *Attempt to mutate in notificatio* problem