# Validate an empty textbox?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, textbox, verification

I am currently coding a gui and want to verify that the user fills in the textbox a String. I tried that:

```
String name = textBoxes.get(0).getText();
if(name.isEmpty()) {
    showError("Pls insert a name!"); 
} else{
    name = textBoxes.get(0).getText();
}
```

But that really does not work? It seems to be that there is sth. "inside" the textbox, even if I do not fill sth. in.(I tried sysout and got that:

```
'                            '
```

So my question is, how to verify if a textbox is empty or not?

Comment: You could also have a look at [Java Swing: Implementing a validity check of input values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997742/java-swing-implementing-a-validy-check-of-input-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your textBox is returning a string full of space characters. Try using `name.trim().isEmpty()` instead of just name.isEmpty() to remove those extra spaces before you do anything with it.

`trim()` removes leading and trailing white spaces. 
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on which text box you are using. If you using the JTextField from javax.swing you'll want to use `x.getText()` to get the entire thing.