# while loop not repeating after setting to false

Tags: java, while-loop

```
  boolean gotGoodGenInput = false;
  while (!gotGoodGenInput)
  {

    gotGoodGenInput = true;

    String inputGen = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    (
      "Enter your Generation \n" +
      "It must be a number from 0 to 25"
    ); 

    if(inputGen != null)
    {  

      if (inputGen.isEmpty() || !inputGen.matches("[0-9]*")) 
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (
          null,
          "Please input a number from 0 to 25",
          "Error",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
        );
        gotGoodGenInput = false;
      }

      int GenNumber = Integer.parseInt(inputGen);

      if (GenNumber < 0 || GenNumber > 25)
      {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (
          null,
          "Your number can't be less than 0 or greater than 25",
          "Error",
          JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE
        );
        gotGoodGenInput = false;
      }

    }
    else
    {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
```

Hello the issue I am having is that if a user enters "a" (as an example) then they will get the error "please input a number from 0 to 25" from

```
 if (inputGen.isEmpty() || !inputGen.matches("[0-9]*"))
```

and it's supposed to restart the loop when it hits gotGoodGenInput = false;

but it keeps going to the next part where it will try to parse the int but of course it will error since "a" is not an int

so my issue is why is it not starting over when it reaches gotGoodGenInput = false; in the first if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the line

```
gotGoodGenInput = false;
```

add the line

```
continue;
```

which will restart from the beginning of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just setting `gotGoodGenInput=false` is not enough to restart the loop.  You have changed the value of your variable, but you haven't told the program not to continue with the loop.

You probably want to add a `continue;` statement after each time you set `gotGoodGenInput` to `false` to get the behavior you describe.

You may also want to explore Swing's InputVerifiers.  Check out this thread: [Java Swing: Implementing a validity check of input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997742/java-swing-implementing-a-validy-check-of-input-values).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a missing **else** after the **if** statement where you check whether the string is empty or different from an integer. Like this it will enter the **if** statement, but then continue to the next one where it tries to parse the int.