# how to manipulate JTable return value on specified column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, tablecelleditor

I have a JTable that has two columns (*editable JTable*). When a user types something in the second column, my requirement is as follows:

- user can only typewrite a number and comma
- when user type wrong character, it will beep `(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();`)

How do I go about achieving this? (*if it jtextfield it need document filter or plain document etc, if it JTable, then how?*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) that is capable of returning a text component (`JTextField`) that has a [`DocumentFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) attached to it capable of filtering the incoming text as you require.

You might like to take a look at

- [Limit the Characters in the text field using document listner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812844/limit-the-characters-in-the-text-field-using-document-listner/12812935#12812935)
- [MDP's Weblog](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter)
- [accept only a single digit in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224455/accept-only-a-single-digit-in-java/13224591#13224591)
- [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) (look for "Implementing a Document Filter")

**UPDATED with example**

> if it jtextfield it need document filter or plain document etc, if it
>   JTable, then how?

Read the tutorials, ask questions specific to the problem you're having.  It's important that you understand why things are done in a certain way rather then simply copying and pasting some one else code, otherwise you won't know when you're copying bad ideas ;)

```
public class TestFilteredCellEditor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFilteredCellEditor();
    }

    public TestFilteredCellEditor() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new FilteredEditorPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class FilteredEditorPane extends JPanel {

        public FilteredEditorPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
            TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
            columnModel.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new FilteredTableEditor());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));
        }
    }

    public class FilteredTableEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private JTextField editor;

        public FilteredTableEditor() {
            editor = new JTextField();
            ((AbstractDocument) editor.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new NumericDocumentFilter());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return editor.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            if (value instanceof String) {
                editor.setText((String) value);
            } else {
                editor.setText(null);
            }
            return editor;
        }
    }

    public class NumericDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                String string, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(string);
            boolean isBad = false;
            for (int i = buffer.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                char ch = buffer.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                    buffer.deleteCharAt(i);
                    isBad = true;
                }
            }
            if (isBad) {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            }
            super.insertString(fb, offset, buffer.toString(), attr);
        }

        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb,
                int offset, int length, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
            if (length > 0) {
                fb.remove(offset, length);
            }
            insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
        }
    }

    public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return String.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fatal flaw in my answer...didn't think it through :) +1 for yours!

Comment: +1 why reinvent the wheel, put there JFormattedTextField then getColumnClass should be returns proper Class

Comment: hufh.. thanks a lot.. apologize for long response.. the reason is i still try to solve this in last several day.. i think no one will show me the code.. so i keep try it(based you first answer) and will back here if i already solve it.. at the end i still can't solve it until u edit your answer.. thanks.. however i still can't write a number in jtable(based on your code) but i got the point now(based on your code) thanks a lot it help..