# Block text-writing after n characters

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jtextcomponent, documentfilter

I have this code, that "disables" user input on a JTextField after n characters are inserted:

```
JTextField tf = new JTextField();
tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        if (((JTextField) e.getSource()).getText().length() > n) {
            e.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

It works, but i was wondering if there is an alternative, because i tried it on an old slow computer and when i type something in the textfield the letter is added, then it disappear... I would like to avoid using `e.consume()` after user input and directly prevent insertion instead.

Is it possible?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that i used `JTextField` only for this example, but i would like this code to work with generic text input components like `JTextPane`, `JTextArea`, etc

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield

Comment: It seems like documentFilter is the way to go for all these cases. JTextPane supports documents, and as for JTextArea: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/java-jtextarea-limiting-amount-of-characters-entered-155469/#post805335

Comment: Anything that implements the `JTextComponent` interface has a document. If the specific document supports the setDocumentFilter (e.g. as in `AbstractDocument`) you can use the this method . http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `DocumentSizeFilter` class

Which is made for this specific use:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextComponentDemoProject/src/components/DocumentSizeFilter.java

Tutorial on how to do this within **Implementing a Document Filter** Section:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter

**Quoting from there:**

> To limit the characters allowed in the document, DocumentSizeFilter
>   overrides the DocumentFilter class's insertString method, which is
>   called each time that text is inserted into the document. It also
>   overrides the replace method, which is most likely to be called when
>   the user pastes in new text. In general, text insertion can result
>   when the user types or pastes in new text, or when the setText method
>   is called. Here is the DocumentSizeFilter class's implementation of
>   the insertString method:

```
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs,
                         String str, AttributeSet a)
    throws BadLocationException {

    if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()) <= maxCharacters)
        super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
    else
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); }
```