# How to fix the number of characters to be entered in a jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I should stop user from entering more than (lets say 10 ro 20 characters) in a text field because if he enters more than specified limit it throws exception from the database..

I tried to use custom code `Textfield_txt = new javax.swing.JTextField(10);`

but it is not working

please give your adivce on this

Comment: There's an example about this in the swing docs I think. Go ask Google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield