# limit the number of characters of a JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I want to limit the number of characters to be inserted in a JTextField  to 10 character. I use a graphical interface under netbeans.thanks.

Comment: add a `documentListener` to you `JTextField`

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield. That is an old answer. The Swing API has evolved and the more current solution would be to use a DocumentFilter, so I re opened the question.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the user from entering more the 10 charaters in a textfield you can use a document.

Create a simple document by extending `PlainDocument` and to change the behavior override

```
public void insertString(...) throws BadLocationException
```

This is an example

```
public class MaxLengthTextDocument extends PlainDocument {
    //Store maximum characters permitted
    private int maxChars;

    @Override
    public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
            throws BadLocationException {
        // the length of string that will be created is getLength() + str.length()
        if(str != null && (getLength() + str.length() < maxChars)){
            super.insertString(offs, str, a);
        }
    }

}
```

After this, only insert your implementation in `JTextField`, this way:

```
...
MaxLengthTextDocument maxLength = new MaxLengthTextDocument();
maxLength.setMaxChars(10); 

jTextField.setDocument(maxLength);
...
```

And that's it!

Comment: Quick post, I know this is old but `(getLength() + str.length() < maxChars))` should really be `(getLength() + str.length() <= maxChars))` otherwise one less character than what is set will be allowed into the text field. Thanks for the post though, just helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Best thing is you will get running demo ;)

```
class JTextFieldLimit extends PlainDocument {
  private int limit;
  JTextFieldLimit(int limit) {
    super();
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  JTextFieldLimit(int limit, boolean upper) {
    super();
    this.limit = limit;
  }

  public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
    if (str == null)
      return;

    if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit) {
      super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
    }
  }
}

public class Main extends JFrame {
  JTextField textfield1;

  JLabel label1;

  public static void main(String[]args){
      new Main().init();
  }
  public void init() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    label1 = new JLabel("max 10 chars");
    textfield1 = new JTextField(15);
    add(label1);
    add(textfield1);
    textfield1.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(10));

    setSize(300,300);
    setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for a more current solution.

This solution will work an any Document, not just a PlainDocument.