# Using Methods to limit the number of Characters in a jTextfield

Tags: java

I'm here to get a problem solved that has been eating me up.
I want a `jTextField` to accept just three characters; no numbers or special characters.
I don't know the solution, either to put a loop for this or a selection statement, or something else. I tried several times, using different Methods() for making it work. It seems to be easy but anyway I'm unable to find the final solution for this.

Need help guys! Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? You need to at least try before anyone here gives you a solution as this sounds like homework. Post your code and we'll help.

Comment: Hope this link will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953208/value-change-listener-to-jtextfield.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield

Comment: @DanielMaclam I don't think this is homework. Still, would be nice to see some effort from OP.