# Enforcing limited character range for jtextfield code not working

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

I am trying to use KeyEvent to limit the characters in a jTextField that it can take as input on the KeyTyped event using the following code:

```java
private void userIDFieldKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     
        char c = evt.getKeyChar();
        if(c!=KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && c!=KeyEvent.VK_DELETE){
            if (Character.isLetter(c) && Character.isDigit(c)){
            } else {
                evt.consume();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the above code is not working as expected, it do not take any character as input, as it is clear from the code I am trying to input only AlphaNumeric characters, is there any way to remove this problem? Also I have tried using `KeyEvent.VK_ALPHANUMERIC` but it didn't work either.

Edit:
What I mean by limiting the characters is that the text field can take input only certain characters which I have allowed and not that to stop takinginput after a certain number of characters has been alread been entered.

Comment: Don't use a `KeyListener` for that, use a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To limit the number of characters in JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519151/how-to-limit-the-number-of-characters-in-jtextfield)

Answer (score 0):

I think that `JFormattedTextField` handles all your requirements. It can limit the number of characters entered, as well as filter out non-required characters. Here is a small example. The `MaskFormatter` is responsible for handling the required limitations.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

/**
 * For testing class {@code javax.swing.JFormattedTextField}
 */
public class FmTxtFld implements Runnable {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JFormattedTextField  fmtTxtFld;

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        try {
            showGui();
        }
        catch (ParseException xParse) {
            xParse.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showGui() throws ParseException {
        frame = new JFrame("FmTxtFld");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Ten alphanumeric characters, i.e. letter or digit.
        MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("AAAAAAAAAA"); //throws java.text.ParseException

        fmtTxtFld = new JFormattedTextField(formatter);
        fmtTxtFld.setColumns(10);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("JFormattedTextField");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(fmtTxtFld);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FmTxtFld instance = new FmTxtFld();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
    }
}
```

If you run the above code you will see that the text field only echoes valid characters, i.e. only letters and digits, and will also not accept more that 10 characters.